# Deploy Web application to a different Azure account in Visual Studio Team Service

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Is it possible to use a second azure account to set where my application will be deployed?

> For example, using my account to manage the project, but use my
>   client's azure subscription to deploys the web application.

In the video of [Service Endpoints](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/library/service-endpoints) at 13:27, their azure interface have some options that I don't. May be because of my free subscription. 
[image: Azure subscription panel]

Comment: What's the result after running that PowerShell script and configure service endpoint.

Comment: It works, thanks starain-MSFT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to this article below to setup an Azure Resource Manager endpoint, then deploy your app to Azure by using [Azure App Service Deploy step/task](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/AzureRmWebAppDeployment) with that endpoint.

[How to Setup an Azure Resource Manager Endpoint](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/10/04/automating-azure-resource-group-deployment-using-a-service-principal-in-visual-studio-online-buildrelease-management/) (Manual configuration section)

Comment: Hey starain-MSFT, thanks for your answer. I got sick, so I'll update my question as soon as I can

Comment: @ItaloPessoa I updated the link, try to download the PowerShell script (Manual configuration section) and get the necessary information directly. (https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-rm-documentation/blob/master/Azure/SPNCreation.ps1)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are talking about VSTS Online Build/Release management?  If so, then yes.  In order to connect to Azure, you need to create [Service Endpoints](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/library/service-endpoints) that can then be used in the various build/release pipeline steps.

Basically, you can log in with your account to manage the pipeline, but then kick off a task that executes against the configured Service Endpoint for the destination subscription.

Comment: Hey CtrlDot, thanks for your answer. I got sick, so I'll update my question as soon as I can.